# Pandas replace values in dataframe conditionally based on string compare

Tags: python, string, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe as below with 3 columns. I want to compare each column to see if the value matches a particular string, and if yes, replace the value with NaN.

For example, if there are 5 values in column 1 of the data frame:

```
abcd
abcd
defg
abcd
defg
```

and if the comparison string is `defg`, the end result for column 1 in the data frame should be.

```
abcd
abcd
NaN
abcd
NaN
```

Comment: @ pseudocode425, if any of the solution worked for you and best fit then accept that as an answer !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use pandas in-built solution Using `replace` method as a regex and inplace method to make it permanent in the dataframe, while use numpy to replace the matching values to `NaN`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

**Example DataFrame:**

```
df
   col1
0  abcd
1  abcd
2  defg
3  abcd
4  defg
```

**Result:**

```
df['col1'].replace(['defg'], np.nan, regex=True, inplace=True)
   df
       col1
    0  abcd
    1  abcd
    2   NaN
    3  abcd
    4   NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [numpy where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to set values based on boolean conditions:

```
import numpy as np
df["col_name"] = np.where(df["col_name"]=="defg", np.nan, df["col_name"])
```

Obviously replace `col_name` with whatever your actual column name is.

An alternative is to use pandas `.loc` to change the values in the DataFrame in place:

```
df.loc[df["col_name"]=="defg", "col_name"] = np.nan
```

Comment: I get a TypeError: invalid type comparison with this, it's comparing a Series to a Str?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mask`, this will replace 'defg' in the entire dataframe with NaN:

```
df.mask(df == 'defg')
```

Output:

```
      0
0  abcd
1  abcd
2   NaN
3  abcd
4   NaN
```

You can do this for a column also:

```
df['col1'].mask(df['col1'] == 'defg')
```

Or using replace as @pygo suggest in his solution

```
df['col1'].replace('defg',np.nan)
```

Comment: @Scott Boston - how does this work if I only wanted to do the replace in a particular column and not the entire data set?

Comment: @pseudocode425, try the alternative answer as i provided, i have illustrated that creating a column `col1` as an example.

Comment: However with Scott's answer , simply try like `df.col1.mask(df == 'defg')`  that will give you what you  are asking.

Answer (score 1):

There's a bunch of solutions... If you want to practice with using lambda functions you could always do...

```
df['Col1'] = df.Col1.apply(lambda x: np.nan if x == 'defg' else x)
```

Result:

```
0  abcd
1  abcd
2   NaN
3  abcd
4   NaN
Seconds:  0.0020899999999999253
```

Processing time is probably a little bit slower than the solutions above though after some unit testing.